Period mappings are analytic
In Lawrence-Venkatesh, they constructed a $v$-adic period mapping between $K_v$-analytic spaces. They stated that this mapping is analytic. I didn't know why this holds true. It seems that there may be an analytic description of period mappings which works for both $\mathbb{C}$-analytic spaces and $v$-adic analytic spaces.
